# Python - retrieve info from dictionary list & syntax error

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out a 'simple' dictionary/database with Python, which will retrieve a name from a list of ten, with the requested information. 
i.e. input is 'John phone'; output is 'John's phone number is 0401'.

Apart from being completely stuck on this retrieval of specific information, python has suddenly been giving me a syntax error on the name = raw_input line.

The following is the file i've saved as 'friends':

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

friends = {'John' : {'phone' : '0401',
        'birthday' : '31 July',
        'address' : 'UK',
        'interests' : ['a', 'b', 'c']},
    'Harry' : {'phone' : '0402',
        'birthday' : '2 August',
        'address' : 'Hungary',
        'interests' : ['d', 'e', 'f']}}
name = raw_input ('Who are you looking for? ')
if name in friends: 
print friends[name]"'s phone number is: "['phone']
    # this line is something I haven't tested
    # and so I have a big hunch it's not going to work
else: 
    print 'no data'
```

and this is the error it's giving me:

```python
$ ./friends
File "./friends", line 11
name = raw_input ('Who are you looking for? ')
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please note, this was *not* happening a few hours ago when I was working on the very same file, using terminal on my imac. I haven't altered that line, and I'm absolutely stumped as to why it's playing up!

- also won't work on my pc's cygwin, or another borrowed mac.
- and yes, i've entered chmod +x friends into terminal.

It's probably the simplest, silliest thing, and I've probably completely overlooked something or accidentally bumped a key (it's 1am.. this is due on Monday...), but any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm almost sure there's a missing `{` or `]` in your code somewhere (on one of the files). Anyway, there's another syntax error, not on this line

Comment: That usually points to unbalanced parenthesis and/or braces. But in this code example, it's fine.  But you do have another problem. your first print statement will not work, 'phone' isn't accessible that way, not to mention the indenting.  you'll want to access it differently, check out the newer .format() for strings in python.

Comment: Side note: if you're just learning Python, I'd recommend using an editor with syntax checking. My preferred blend is [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) + [sublimelint](https://github.com/lunixbochs/sublimelint/)

Comment: In my experience, this sort of SyntaxError indicating a valid line usually means you've got a syntax error on an adjacent line that's making Python interpret the line indicated as part of a multiline expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `raw_input()` line works fine here.

You have a syntax error on the "unsure" line. It could read like this:

```
print name + "'s phone number is: " + friends[name]['phone']
```

You could also use format strings:

```
print "%s's phone number is: %s" % (name, friends[name]['phone'])
```

Full `if` block:

```
if name in friends: 
    print "%s's phone number is: %s" % (name, friends[name]['phone'])
else: 
    print 'no data'
```

Otherwise, your code worked for me after copying/pasting directly from your post.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - like I said, half asleep, didn't see the missing closing }.

Comment: also @lunixbochs your 'if' block worked! thank you, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in the line that prints the message and forgot to indent it (that's not optional in python!).

Here are some fixed versions:

```
print name + "'s phone number is: " + friends[name]['phone']
print "%s's phone number is: %s" % (name, friends[name]['phone'])
```

The other lines are perfectly fine, so the error you are getting is rather odd.